# How to restart/delete game data on iPhone 6 IOS 11?

Tags: ios, game-center

I want to restart Clash of Clans from the beginning, but each time I delete the app and re-download it I pick up from where I left off. I tried going into settings into the game center section and couldn't find anything useful. I did the same with iCloud and had the same result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restart clash of clans even if you delete the app, the only way to restart it is to both delete the app and also log out of gamecenter and sign into gamecenter with a different Apple ID.